# Sum of a column with the same name (value) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am using the following query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT
        pegawai_nama,
        COUNT(operasi_operator_dokter) AS total,
        CASE tindakan_golongan WHEN 'KECIL' THEN SUM(tariftindakan_biaya_alkes)
            ELSE 0
        END AS KECIL,
        CASE tindakan_golongan WHEN 'BESAR' THEN SUM(tariftindakan_biaya_alkes)
            ELSE 0
        END AS BESAR,
        CASE tindakan_golongan WHEN 'KHUSUS' THEN SUM(tariftindakan_biaya_alkes
            ELSE 0
        END AS SEDANG

    FROM
        t_operasi

    LEFT JOIN m_pasien On t_operasi.operasi_pasien_norm = m_pasien.pasien_norm
    LEFT JOIN t_pendaftaran on t_operasi.operasi_pendaftaran_id = t_pendaftaran.pendaftaran_id
    LEFT JOIN m_tindakan ON t_operasi.operasi_tindakan_id = m_tindakan.tindakan_id
    LEFT JOIN m_tarif_tindakan ON m_tindakan.tindakan_id = m_tarif_tindakan.m_tindakan_id
    LEFT JOIN m_pegawai ON cast(m_pegawai.pegawai_id as varchar(10)) = t_operasi.operasi_operator_dokter
    LEFT JOIN t_diagnosa_pasien ON t_diagnosa_pasien.t_pendaftaran_id = t_pendaftaran.pendaftaran_id
    LEFT JOIN m_icd ON m_icd.icd_id = t_diagnosa_pasien.m_icd_id

    WHERE operasi_id IS NOT NULL AND tindakan_golongan IN ('KECIL', 'BESAR', 'KHUSUS', 'SEDANG', '')
    GROUP BY pegawai_nama, tindakan_golongan;
```

However, the result below is not what I am after:

[image: Result of my code]

Instead I would like the following result:

```
pegawai_nama            total    kecil    besar    sedang    khusus
DR. JOKO TRIYONO, SPM    2        189000   0        909700    0
DR. DJOHAR ANWAR         3        567000   0        0         0
```

Comment: Related: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my new code (based on [Georgi Raychev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524112/sum-of-column-with-same-name-value-in-postgresql/50524331#50524331)):

```
SELECT
        sub.pegawai_nama,
        sum(sub.total) as total,
        sum(sub.kecil) as kecil,
        sum(sub.besar) as besar,
        sum(sub.sedang) as sedang,
        sum(sub.khusus) as khusus

    FROM (

    SELECT
    pegawai_nama,
    COUNT(operasi_operator_dokter) AS total,
        CASE tindakan_golongan WHEN 'KECIL' THEN SUM(tariftindakan_biaya_alkes +
                                                                                                    tariftindakan_biaya_cover +tariftindakan_biaya)
            ELSE 0
        END AS kecil,
        CASE tindakan_golongan WHEN 'BESAR' THEN SUM(tariftindakan_biaya_alkes +
                                                                                                    tariftindakan_biaya_cover +tariftindakan_biaya)
            ELSE 0
        END AS besar,
        CASE tindakan_golongan WHEN 'KHUSUS' THEN SUM(tariftindakan_biaya_alkes +
                                                                                                    tariftindakan_biaya_cover +tariftindakan_biaya)
            ELSE 0
        END AS khusus,
        CASE tindakan_golongan WHEN 'SEDANG' THEN SUM(tariftindakan_biaya_alkes +
                                                                                                    tariftindakan_biaya_cover +tariftindakan_biaya)
            ELSE 0
        END AS sedang

        FROM
        t_operasi

    LEFT JOIN m_pasien On t_operasi.operasi_pasien_norm = m_pasien.pasien_norm
    LEFT JOIN t_pendaftaran on t_operasi.operasi_pendaftaran_id = t_pendaftaran.pendaftaran_id
    LEFT JOIN m_tindakan ON t_operasi.operasi_tindakan_id = m_tindakan.tindakan_id
    LEFT JOIN m_tarif_tindakan ON m_tindakan.tindakan_id = m_tarif_tindakan.m_tindakan_id
    LEFT JOIN m_pegawai ON cast(m_pegawai.pegawai_id as varchar(10)) = t_operasi.operasi_operator_dokter
    LEFT JOIN t_diagnosa_pasien ON t_diagnosa_pasien.t_pendaftaran_id = t_pendaftaran.pendaftaran_id
    LEFT JOIN m_icd ON m_icd.icd_id = t_diagnosa_pasien.m_icd_id

    WHERE operasi_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY pegawai_nama, tindakan_golongan
    ) AS sub

    GROUP BY sub.pegawai_nama
```

;

And this is the result:

[New Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYI1y.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Just have this as a nested query, and group it again:

```
select pegawai_nama, sum(total) as total , sum(kecil) as kecil, sum(besar) as besar, sum(sedang) as sedang
from (

-- insert your query here

) sub
group by pegawai_nama
```

Comment: whoaaa thank, your answer make my code run suitable with my expetation

Comment: @M.Syafi why don't you +1 this answer if it helped you? If it helps get +1 and accept.

Comment: but my reputation lest than 15

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the "tindakan_golongan" column from the GROUP BY.

Comment: if I remove tindakan_golongan from group by will error and the comment is " ERROR:  column "m_tindakan.tindakan_golongan" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: I would then suggest creating a temporary table with no group by, to gather together the data, and then do a very simply select on the temporary table using GROUP BY.

Comment: In fact you might even be able to do a nested SELECT as follows: SELECT

Comment: Okay, I will try this one. Thank you

Comment: Sorry I pressed Enter prematurely, but someone posted an answer that was basically exactly what I was thinking.